# Scala Iteratively build lists

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-collections

As a Scala beginner I am still struggling working with immutable lists. All I am trying to do append elements to my list. Here's an example of what I am trying to do.

```
val list = Seq()::Nil
val listOfInts = List(1,2,3)
listOfInts.foreach {case x=>
 list::List(x)
}
```

expecting that I would end up with a list of lists: *List(List(1),List(2),List(3))*

Coming from java I am used to just using list.add(new ArrayList(i)) to get the same result. Am I way off here?

Comment: Maybe instead of downvoting, SO should have an option to flag, "Did not take Coursera."

Comment: The return type of `foreach` is `Unit`, so you don't end up with anything. You probably want `map`?

Answer (score 1):

Since the `List` is *immutable* you can not modify the `List` in place.

To construct a List of 1 item Lists from a List, you can `map` over the List.  The difference between `forEach` and `map` is that `forEach` returns nothing, i.e. `Unit`, while `map` returns a List from the returns of some function.

```
scala> def makeSingleList(j:Int):List[Int] = List(j)
makeSingleList: (j: Int)List[Int]

scala> listOfInts.map(makeSingleList)
res1: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1), List(2), List(3))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are tutorials on the documentation page.

There is a blurb for [ListBuffer](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/concrete-mutable-collection-classes.html#list-buffers), if you swing that way.

Otherwise,

```
scala> var xs = List.empty[List[Int]]
xs: List[List[Int]] = List()

scala> (1 to 10) foreach (i => xs = xs :+ List(i))

scala> xs
res9: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1), List(2), List(3), List(4), List(5), List(6), List(7), List(8), List(9), List(10))
```

You have a choice of using a mutable builder like `ListBuffer` or a local var and returning the collection you build.

In the functional world, you often build by prepending and then reverse:

```
scala> var xs = List.empty[List[Int]]
xs: List[List[Int]] = List()

scala> (1 to 10) foreach (i => xs = List(i) :: xs)

scala> xs.reverse
res11: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1), List(2), List(3), List(4), List(5), List(6), List(7), List(8), List(9), List(10))
```

Comment: Correct answer because it works, bad answer because it shows a bad practice and an anti-pattern

Comment: Sorry, @Dici, but every function that wants to build a collection has a choice of whether to use a mutable builder imperatively or using an immutable collection monadically. This is a point driven home over and again, so I make it again. The question is how to build them, not how to use map, etc.

Comment: So what is the advantage of your snippet over the idiomatic `xs ::: (1 to 10)` ?

Comment: @Dici care to explain why it's an antipattern? ;-)

Comment: @Dici might mean appending to a List is bad, which is true.

Comment: @om-nom-nom Scala *allows* imperative style but *encourages* functional programming. This is clearly not in the spirit of the language and is horribly verbose

Comment: @Dici For example, Odersky just complained in his talk on dotty that everyone changed his imperative loops to functional stuff in scalac and it all got slow.

Comment: @som-snytt I would argue that Scala is built for functional style whereas Java is not. In Java, `foreach` is not idiomatic so if it does not bring any value why would you bear the cost of constructing a `Stream` just for avoiding writing a loop ? In Scala `foreach` can be unefficient and using `while` performs better, but it's not idiomatic. A Scala programmer should consider imperative idioms only if the functional equivalent is too unefficient for the requirements of the application

Comment: If you have read Odersky first edition of `Programming in Scala`, the use of `var` is clearly discouraged whenever possible. In the team I work with (in Java), effectively final variables are considered a best practice. Of course it's still Java and you definitely have some cases of accumulators, counters and this kind of things, but this is not something you want when you have an obvious syntax for avoiding it

Comment: @Dici just mind you that you're trying to convince [avid commiter to scala language (som-snytt)](https://github.com/scala/scala/commits?author=som-snytt) what is idiomatic in scala and what is not )

Comment: @om-nom-nom so what should I do ? Kneel before him and ask for mercy ? As any programmer, he might have different views on a topic than his peers. As any human, he might be wrong. Even Odersky could be wrong about what Scala should be, and regret some early design decisions. That's why there is a community, and debates

Comment: *As any programmer, he might have different views on a topic than his peers. As any human, he might be wrong. Even Odersky could be wrong about what Scala should be, and regret some early design decisions. That's why there is a community, and debates* couldn't agree more. Just to make it clear -- I am not trying to offend you (though *I am* the person who downvoted your answer because it promotes highly inefficient code with the sauce of idiomacy), it just that I can't agree with the whole black and white "mutability is bad" flow in this conversation

Comment: @Dici I only know what they tell me. I don't disagree w/u about prefer functional, but imperative with local mutables has its place & also easy for Java folks to grok. Until they know better. As a ref only, https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=kkTFx3-duc8#t=1069

Comment: Mutability isn't bad if you use mutable collections, but don't tell me that populating Scala lists with `var`s and `foreach`  is good. BTW, `:::` is unefficient only if the first list is longer than the second one, which is not the case here. (For your video, doesn't the very first slide sum up my previous comments ?)

Comment: @Dici We'll agree that you think this is bad, and you'll submit a PR. https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.7/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L140

Comment: @som-snytt that's not what the op is doing. He said he expected `List(1) :: List(2) :: List(3)`. Where do you see a reverse order ? I agree the question can be misleading because the code reverses the list (at least it would do so if it was mutable). However, it reverses the right-side list not the left-side one, so the method you pointed does not apply. I'm a bit unsure why you are showing me this. Is this to prove that while loops are more efficient in Scala ? Oh wait, I said it 7 comments ago.

Answer (score 1):

Below is copy and pasted from the Scala REPL with added print statement to see what is happening:

```
scala>     val list = Seq()::Nil
list: List[Seq[Nothing]] = List(List())

scala>     val listOfInts = List(1,2,3)
listOfInts: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala>     listOfInts.foreach { case x=>
 |       println(list::List(x))
 |     }
List(List(List()), 1)
List(List(List()), 2)
List(List(List()), 3)
```

During the first iteration of the foreach loop, you are actually taking the first element of listOfInts (which is 1), putting that in a new list (which is List(1)), and then adding the new element list (which is List(List()) ) to the beginning of List(1).  This is why it prints out List(List(List()), 1).

Since your list and listOfInts are both immutable, you can't change them.  All you can do is perform something on them, and then return a new list with the change.  In your case list::List(x) inside the loop actually doesnt do anything you can see unless you print it out.

Answer (score 1):

Given **`val listOfInts = List(1,2,3)`**, and you want the final result as **`List(List(1),List(2),List(3))`**.

Another nice trick I can think of is **sliding(Groups elements in fixed size blocks by passing a "sliding window" over them)**

```
scala> val listOfInts = List(1,2,3)
listOfInts: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> listOfInts.sliding(1)
res6: Iterator[List[Int]] = non-empty iterator

scala> listOfInts.sliding(1).toList
res7: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1), List(2), List(3))

// If pass 2 in sliding, it will be like
scala> listOfInts.sliding(2).toList
res8: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2), List(2, 3))
```

For more about the sliding, you can have a read about **sliding** in **scala.collection.IterableLike**.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply map over this list to create a List of Lists.
It maintains Immutability and functional approach.

```
scala> List(1,2,3).map(List(_))
res0: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1), List(2), List(3))
```

Or you, can also use Tail Recursion :

```
@annotation.tailrec
def f(l:List[Int],res:List[List[Int]]=Nil) :List[List[Int]] = {
    if(l.isEmpty) res else f(l.tail,res :+ List(l.head))
}

scala> f(List(1,2,3))
res1: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1), List(2), List(3))
```

Answer (score 0):

In scala you have <s>two</s> (three, as @som-snytt has shown) options -- opt for a mutable collection (like Buffer):

```
scala> val xs = collection.mutable.Buffer(1)
// xs: scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer(1)

scala> xs += 2
// res10: xs.type = ArrayBuffer(1, 2)

scala> xs += 3
// res11: xs.type = ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 3)
```

As you can see, it works just like you would work with lists in Java. The other option you have, and in fact it's highly encouraged, is to opt to processing list functionally, that's it, you take some function and apply it to each and every element of collection:

```
scala> val ys = List(1,2,3,4).map(x => x + 1)
// ys: List[Int] = List(2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> def isEven(x: Int) = x % 2 == 0
// isEven: (x: Int)Boolean

scala> val zs = List(1,2,3,4).map(x => x * 10).filter(isEven)
// zs: List[Int] = List(10, 20, 30, 40)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// input: List(1,2,3)
// expected output: List(List(1), List(2), List(3))

val myList: List[Int] = List(1,2,3)
val currentResult = List()

def buildIteratively(input: List[Int], currentOutput: List[List[Int]]): List[List[Int]] = input match {
  case Nil => currentOutput
  case x::xs => buildIteratively(xs, List(x) :: currentOutput)
}

val result = buildIteratively(myList, currentResult).reverse
```

Answer (score -2):

You say in your question that the list is immutable, so you **do** are aware that you cannot mutate it ! All operations on Scala lists return a **new** list. By the way, even in Java using a `foreach` to populate a collection is considered a bad practice. The Scala idiom for your use-case is :

```
list ::: listOfInts
```

Shorter, clearer, more functional, more idiomatic and easier to reason about (mutability make things more "complicated" especially when writing lambda expressions because it breaks the semantic of a pure function). There is no good reason to give you a different answer.

If you want mutability, probably for performance purposes, use a mutable collection such as `ArrayBuffer`.